# How to continuously send and receive packets?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, packet

I am programming a server / client communication system where a client requests to log in to the server and can request to view other client's online status. I can make the client log in fine, but when I try to log in (successfully) and then send another packet requesting another client's information, the server does not receive that packet.

the main part of the server, not the technical connection stuff starting from bind Server:

```
Users client[2]; //I intialized them already

//Bind
bind(WelcomeSocket, (sockaddr*)&SvrAddr, sizeof(SvrAddr));

//listening
listen(WelcomeSocket, 5);

//temp users
Users temp;

//while loop for the connection 
while (1) {

    ConnectionSocket = accept(WelcomeSocket, NULL, NULL);



    if (recv(ConnectionSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0))
        cout << "WORKEDDDDDDDD" << endl;

    memcpy(&temp, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Users));

    cout << temp.message << temp.userName << endl << endl;

    //check which message type is being sent
    switch(temp.message) {

    //if message type 1
    case 1 :
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            //if receieved username matches with any username in the database
            if (strcmp(temp.userName, client[i].userName) == 0) {

                //assign the recieved users information to the matched one in database
                strcpy(client[i].userName, temp.userName);
                client[i].online = true;
                client[i].message = 2;

                cout << client[i].userName << endl << client[i].online << endl;

                //send the acknowledgement packet
                send(ConnectionSocket, (char *)&client[i], sizeof(struct Users), 0);
            }

        }
        closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
        break;

    //if message type 3
    case 3 :
        cout << "3";
        break;

    default :
        break;

    }

}

closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
WSACleanup();
}
```

Client:

```
connect(ClientSocket, (sockaddr*)&SvrAddr, sizeof(SvrAddr));



//cout << "Name: ";
//cin >> login;

//Send request to login
int log;
char * name = new char[128];
char * request = new char[128];
Users client;
Users talkto;



    cout << "To login press (1). ";
    cin >> log;
    flushall();

    if (log == 1) {

        cout << "Username : ";
        cin.getline(name, 128, '\n');
        flushall();

        //Set client login info
        strcpy(client.userName, name);
        client.message = 1;



        send(ClientSocket, (char *)&client, sizeof(struct Users), 0);


        //Recieve acknowledgement
        recv(ClientSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0);
        //create temp users
        Users temp;

        memcpy(&temp, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Users));



        if (temp.message == 2) {

            cout << "Enter user for user information: ";
            cin.getline(talkto.userName, 128, '\n');
            flushall();
            talkto.message = 3;

            //send request for user information packet
            if (send(ClientSocket, (char *)&talkto, sizeof(struct Users), 0))
            cout << "SENDT" << endl;
        }

        //cout << temp.userName << endl << temp.online << endl << temp.message;

        closesocket(ClientSocket);


WSACleanup();
```

}

The structure for users

```
struct Users {

int message;
char userName[50];
char ipAddress[50];
int PortNumber;
bool online;

};
```

Not sure why it's not receiving information more than one time

Comment: You're closing the socket in your switch for case 1, so after it receives message type 1, it disconnects the socket.

Comment: Even if I don't close the socket I still get the same problem @DavidOtano

Comment: I know why. Your `accept` function is blocking the rest of the loop waiting for the next client.

Comment: @DavidOtano what would be the solution to fix that then? I took it out of the while loop and while it "worked", i got an infinite loop of messages on my server side

Comment: Please see my answer, I revised it for you.

Comment: Non-blocking sockets should help you, and if you set it up just right, you won't even need threads. http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConnectionSocket = accept(WelcomeSocket, NULL, NULL);
```

You should put that before the loop, not inside, because the `accept` function is waiting for another client, blocking you from receiving another packet.

Also, when your `recv` call returns 0, it means that the connection has closed, and it's the end of the stream, so you should break from your loop when `recv` returns 0, or some unexpected `SOCKET_ERROR`.

Comment: Yes, that will help to serve a single connection. But any other clients will not be able to connect while the connection is open.

Comment: Amazing! I did a if (n == 0) break; and a little fixing on my client side and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Inspired you're right...um while this serves as a simple fix I would probably run into trouble later because I am supposed to be having 2 clients on this server which talk to each other...

Answer (score 0):

For each client connection, your server performs accept-recv-send-closesocket. Period.

A connection to client is closed after the server processes the first packet. You have either to establish a new connection before sending each packet at client side (but that would probably make your login procedure useless) or to make server be able to maintain several concurrent client connections polling them in an infinite loop, maybe in a separate thread(s).

Comment: I have the accept-recv-send-closesocket in a while(1) loop in my server side, but am I missing something to accept more than one packet?

Comment: It's the recv that accepts the packet right? In my server the recv does not receive a packet twice, it stops after the first one do not know why

Comment: Right, 'packets' are received via 'recv' (although for TCP sockets you can receive only streams of data, there are no notion of boundaries, so no one guarantees that `recv` will fetch the whole message, or that if a client sends two messages in a row the first `recv` will not fetch both of them). But the server closes the connection (`closesocket`) and then waits for the next connection (`accept`). If you add the second `recv` right after server's `send` it should work. But that's not how multi-client servers should be designed (while talking to a single client, your server blocks all others).

Comment: Could you provide me with a resource or something that explains how to accept multiple clients on a server for my purpose?